# Bootstrap overrides my styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, margins

I am creating a web template using bootstrap, so I have `bootstrap.min.css` included in the head of the page with some other css files and my own css file is the last one I linked.
In my css file I have made a reset of the elements like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But this code does not effect the elements in the page!, Most of them has margin and padding. and when I inspected them using the DevTools, I found out that this is caused by bootstrap!
Any solutions? or an explanation of what happens here?
**NOTE:** I use Bootstrap 4.1.1

Comment: Are you loading your CSS after you include the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @Joe Hakooz Yes, as I said.

Comment: Missed that. Can you link to your page for us to view?

Comment: probably because the selectors that are used in bootstrap have more priority than the universal selector

Comment: @Joe Hakooz I am sure that there are no problem in the structure or the linked files

Comment: @Chiller I think so too, Any solutions to that?

Comment: adding !important is one solution but it is not recommended... you may wanna override the css with the same structure that is used in bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap has a variable called `$spacer`. Try set it to 0 - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: @Chiller As you said, the first solution is not recommended. and the second one requires setting margin, padding, and box-sizing to every element I create!

Comment: Try adding a class name or id to the container element of your page and then use it in your selector ex : `#mypage * {margin:0;... }`, basically you need to make your selector have more priority than the bootstrap selectors

Comment: As @chiller noted, the specificity of your selector is less than the ones from bootstrap. For margin and padding, the framework will be perpetually winning as almost all bootstrap classes set these styles (you actually want this if you're using bootstrap as nothing will work properly if you succeed in always defeating the rules)

Comment: @Chiller that worked but I cant edit them (margin & padding) after that unless I use another ID for the exact element I want to style. looks like the ID has more priority than I want haha

Comment: @Stand__Sure & Chiller I fond a solution, Thank you v. much :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you integrate bootstrap optional theme? If yes remove it, 
and also css have `!important` for example `body { color: blue !important }`

Comment: No I am not, I just included bootstrap's css and JS files. Also, if I use something like: * { margin: 0 !important; }, I will never be able to change the margin of any element unless I use !important in the style.

Answer (score -1):

Try with !important

```
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

Comment: It will prevent you to modify it after you reset the spacers

Comment: As @EliyaCohen said

Comment: @EliyaCohen yes, but if I wanted to do it manually I would have to go to each "col" "button" "table" etc ... To all the elements the margin 0 manually

Comment: Sometimes the long run is preferred over the short one.

Comment: The right thing is what you say. But he wants something quick. In the end he will decide what to do